# Update OR Create entry from same input field in MEAN stack?

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

i know how to update or insert document in mongodb.
But i don't know how to create functionality that allow a same 'Input' field to insert  or update it.

[image: Here are the fields]

Functionality i want -

1. Create a new entry in array
2. When i change something from previously filled  entry it should update.

My main question is. -

1. Should i handle the query with 'If' commands?
2. Where should i handle the 'If' logic? In angular, server request or inside mongodb?
3. Or is there another way to handle this functionality without 'If' commands?

Comment: According to me best way is, there should be 2 different ways like a submit button when a new entry is inserted, so when submit button is clicked a new entry is generated in mongodb and a _id field is also generated. now when a edit button is clicked that id should be passed with the edited fields to mongodb, now from that id you can update that fields